# Can't split spreadtab longtable using \newcommand

Tags: macros, longtable, spreadtab

Check this example (using packages `longtable` and `spreadtab`) that has **zeroed out rows** at the beginning and at the end. These two rows are made invisible by `\phantom` and are moved up by `[-6.9mm]` at the begininng.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{spreadtab}
\usepackage{longtable}


\begin{document}

\begin{spreadtab}{{longtable}{cccc}}%
@\textbf{ONE} & @\textbf{TWO} & @\textbf{THREE} & @\textbf{FOUR} \\
[-5.6mm]\phantom{:={0}} & \phantom{:={0}} & \phantom{:={0}} & \phantom{:={0 tag(start)}} \\ \hline
5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\ 
5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\
5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\
[-5.6mm]\phantom{:={0}} & \phantom{:={0}} & \phantom{:={0}} & \phantom{:={0 tag(stop)}} \\ \hline
&&& sum(cell(start):cell(stop))
\end{spreadtab}

\end{document}
```

This example works. But what I want is to **split the table** by defining three commands somewhere in the preamble of the document.

First one being `\tablestart` and second one being `\tablestop`. Then I want to define third one `\input_row` which would enable users to easily write the rows.

Like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{spreadtab}
\usepackage{longtable}

\newcommand{\tablestart}{
    \begin{spreadtab}{{longtable}{cccc}}%
        @\textbf{ONE} & @\textbf{TWO} & @\textbf{THREE} & @\textbf{FOUR} \\
            [-5.6mm]\phantom{:={0}} & \phantom{:={0}} & \phantom{:={0}} & \phantom{:={0 tag(start)}} \\ \hline

}

\newcommand{\tablestop}{
        [-5.6mm]\phantom{:={0}} & \phantom{:={0}} & \phantom{:={0}} & \phantom{:={0 tag(stop)}} \\ \hline
    &&& sum(cell(start):cell(stop))
\end{spreadtab}

\newcommand{\inputrow}[4]{
    #1 & #2 & #3 & #4 \\
}

\begin{document}

\tablestart
\inputrow{5}{6}{7}{8}
\inputrow{5}{6}{7}{8}
\inputrow{5}{6}{7}{8}
\tablestop

\end{document}
```

---

### QUESTION:

While first approach works second one fails to render using `xelatex main.tex` returning the error listed below. Why?

```
Runaway argument?
{ [-5.6mm]\phantom {:={0}} & \phantom {:={0}} & \phantom {:={0}} & \phantom \ET
C.
! File ended while scanning use of \@argdef.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
<*> test-v2.tex
```

Comment: You can't have underscores in control sequence names. Try changing `\input_row` to `\inputrow`

Comment: @DonaldHosek I changed it but it will not compile. I also changed the MWE's to have `\inputrow` instead of `\input_row`.

Comment: You can't hide the spreadtab environment like this. It tries to crab the body and fails if \end{spreadtab} is not visible. spreadtab also doesn't like if you hide the rows in a macros. You would have to write commands that expand your content and build a spreadtab and issue this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to build your table beforehand and not hide rows in macros, because `spreadtab` needs to “see” them explicitly.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{spreadtab}
\usepackage{longtable}

\newtoks\tablecontents
\newcommand{\tablestart}{%
  \tablecontents={}% initialize
}
\newcommand{\inputrow}[4]{%
  \tablecontents=\expandafter{\the\tablecontents #1 & #2 & #3 & #4 \\}%
}

\newcommand{\tablestop}{%
  \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
    \unexpanded{%
      \begin{spreadtab}{{longtable}{cccc}}%
      @\textbf{ONE} & @\textbf{TWO} & @\textbf{THREE} & @\textbf{FOUR} \\
      [-5.6mm]\phantom{:={0}} & \phantom{:={0}} & \phantom{:={0}} & \phantom{:={0 tag(start)}} \\
      \hline
    }%
    \the\tablecontents
    \unexpanded{%
      [-5.6mm]\phantom{:={0}} & \phantom{:={0}} & \phantom{:={0}} & \phantom{:={0 tag(stop)}} \\
      \hline
      &&& sum(cell(start):cell(stop))
     \end{spreadtab}%
    }%
  }\x
}

\begin{document}

\tablestart
\inputrow{5}{6}{7}{8}
\inputrow{5}{6}{7}{8}
\inputrow{5}{6}{7}{8}
\tablestop

\end{document}
```

[image]

The new `\tablestart` command does essentially nothing, except initialize the token register to empty.

The `\inputrow` commands incrementally add to the token register and, finally, `\tablestop` ends the business.

Since we need that the contents of `spreadtab` is not hidden in macros, a temporary macro `\x` is defined. It will contain `\endgroup` (it only serves not to leave `\x` defined after the job has finished), then

1. the table preamble (the `\unexpanded` makes sure it's not touched by `\edef`)
2. the table body, obtained from `\the\tablecontents`
3. the table postamble

Then `\x` is executed that typesets the table.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more or maybe point to a similar problem where I can read about this?

Comment: @71GA I added some comments

Comment: Where can I read more about the macros / commands that you used?